# I can't render through the foreign key

Tags: python, django

I have a doubt. **I want to show a name(nombre) of each client (cliente)** with the total amount of money owed, so that each record is in a different cell.
In pycharm I have this written:

> presupuestos.html

```
<tbody>
   {% for pago in pagos %}
   <tr>    
      <td>
         {% for presupuesto in presupuestos %}
         {{presupuesto.cliente.nombre}}
         {% endfor %}
      </td>
      <td>
         {{pago.cantidad_pagada}}
      </td>
   </tr>
   {% endfor%}
</tbody>
```

What happens is that when rendering this:

```
{% for presupuesto in presupuestos %}
        {{presupuesto.cliente.nombre}}
{% endfor %}
```

The name appears, which is what I want to show, **the bad thing is that all the repeated names appear in the same cell.**

But when using this:

```
{{pago.estimate.cliente.nombre}}
```

Nothing appears and

If I put

```
{{pago.estimate}}
```

**'none' appears,** but if there was nothing in the next loop the names would not appear

I do not understand if my problem is due to my view.py or my models, possibly it is due to "estimates" in my payment model but I do not understand how to change it to be able to access that value.

**I also just checked my pg admin and saw that the estimates table says: "null"** in all cells. What does it mean? that the foreign key is not working and that is why the information that I want to show cannot be rendered?

> pagos/models.py

```
class Pagos(models.Model):
    numero_transaccion=models.IntegerField()
    estimate=models.ForeignKey(Presupuestos, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.numero_transaccion}'
```

> presupuestos/models.py

```
class Presupuestos(models.Model):
    cliente= models.ForeignKey(Clientes, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
 

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.cliente}'
```

> clientes/models.py

```
class Clientes(models.Model):
   
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
   

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.nombre}'
```

> views.py

```
def presupuestosIndex(request):

    presupuestos = Presupuestos.objects.all()
    pagos=Pagos.objects.all()
    


    return render(request, "Presupuestos/presupuestos.html", {'presupuestos':presupuestos,'pagos':pagos})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but probably this is what you want?

```
<table>
<tbody>
{% for pago in pagos %}
<tr>
  <td>
     {{pago.estimate}}
  </td>
  <td>
     {{pago.numero_transaccion}}
  </td>
</tr>
{% endfor%}
</tbody>
</table>
```

And you don't need "presupuestos" in your view.